# Volume form on real Grassmanian

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

There exists a unique $SO(4)-$invariant volume form on the real Grassmanian G(2,2). Is it possible to write it down algebraically in Plucker coordinates?

Comment: Careful: to get the Grassmannian to be oriented, you need it to be the Grassmannian of oriented 2-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The volume form is then unique up to rescaling by a nonzero constant.

Comment: In Plucker coordinates, the oriented Grassmannian is a product $S^2 \times S^2$ and the volume form is the product volume form, with equal area on each sphere. See my thesis https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101017

Comment: Thank you! I guess, it gives positive answer to my question.