# When de Rham cohomology classes of real Grassmanian manifold are given by algebraic expressions?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, homogeneous-spaces

Let $G(m,n)$ be a real oriented Grassmanian of oriented $m$ planes in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.  Real de Rham cohomology classes of this space can be represented by $SO(n+m)-$invariant differential forms. In which cases these forms are algebraic in Plucker coordinates?

**Example** *(m=1)* The invariant volume form on $G(1,n-1)=\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is 
$$\dfrac{p_1dp_2 \wedge dp_3 \wedge ... \wedge dp_n-p_2dp_1 \wedge dp_3 \wedge ... \wedge dp_n+...+(-1)^{n-1}p_n dp_1 \wedge dp_2 \wedge ... \wedge dp_{n-1} }{(\sum{p_i^2})^{n/2}}.$$

**Example** *(m=2)* Invariant volume form on $Gr(2,4)$ has such a presentation, as was pointed out in comments to my previous question, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258135/volume-form-on-real-grassmanian). The denominator is equal to $(\sum{p_{ij}^2})^{3}.$